# $X^5 - 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_5]$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

How can I prove that $X^5 - 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_5]$ please ?

Comment: What are its roots?

Comment: Since the polynomial has degree 5, it won't suffice to look at the roots.

Comment: I assume your notation means $\zeta_5$ is a primitive 5th root of unity. Can you identify the degree of the field extension $[\mathbb Q[\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]2]:Q[\zeta_5]$? What does it tell you about the factorization of $X^5-2$ in $Q[\zeta_5]$?

Comment: I can't identify it, this is the problem.

Comment: @Martin: I beg to differ: knowing the five roots of $X^5 - 2$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is very informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left[\Bbb Q(\zeta_5):\Bbb Q\right]=\phi(5)=4\;,\;\;[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]2):\Bbb Q]=5$$

so

$$\,[\Bbb Q(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]2):\Bbb Q]=\begin{cases}[\Bbb Q(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]2):\Bbb Q(\zeta_5)][\Bbb Q(\zeta_5):\Bbb Q]\\{}\\ [\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]2,\zeta_5):\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]2)][\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]2:\Bbb Q]\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;$$

and now go back to Greg's hint...